# Integrate autotools project with broken out-of-tree build in OE/Yocto

Tags: autotools, yocto, openembedded

I am packaging an autotools based upstream project for use with OE/Yocto.
Yocto will try to build the project out-of-tree (separate from the source).
This fails miserable. I have validated that this is not related to the OE/Yocto setup by trying an out-tree-build on my regular desktop. It fails in the same way.

How can I integrate an autotools project with broken out-of-tree build in OE/Yocto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The recommended solution is to fix the build system to work with out-of-tree builds but there is also a workaround:

```
inherit autotools-brokensep
```

Use that instead of inheriting autotools.